# Checkboxes and Radio buttons in Django ModelForm

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms

Welcome friends,

I'm a newbie in Django. I need your help. Seriously.

I want to add checkboxes and radio button in my form.

Any help will be appreciated.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from shop.models import Product

class Order(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Order

class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'address', 'postal_code', 'city']
```

**create.html**

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    Checkout
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1>Checkout</h1>

    <form action="." method="post" class="order-form">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <p><input type="submit" value="Place order"></p>
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.Please help.

**UPDATE**

How to add select option ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can do something like this

```
CHOICES=[('item1','item 1'),
         ('item2','item 2')]
class OrderCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    postal_code = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    ....
class Meta:
    model = Order
    fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'address', 'postal_code', 'city']
```

similarly, you can do for the other field also

and for checkbox, you can define it as a BooleanFileld and you can use

```
{{ form.paid }}
```

in you template.

Comment: Your idea is good. I just had to change form.as_p  on form.as_ul. But I prefer to use "Rendering fields manually" in temaple.

Answer (score 2):

The form will be rendered with the field types you define in the model:

- BooleanField is rendered as a checkbox, paid in your case.
- ChoiceField can be rendered as radio buttons with the appropiate widget.

You can redefine the widgets in class OrderCreateForm:

`CHOICES = [('option1','label 1'), ('option2','label 2')] 
some_field = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES,widget=forms.RadioSelect())`